# MySQL search field with double '@' sign

Tags: mysql, search

I have a db table which is stored few thousand of member's email, some of the email was entry with double email address within a field, for example is like `abc@site.comxyz@site.com`, how can I filter/search these kind of entry with double `@` sign?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT email FROM t1 WHERE email LIKE '%@%@%'
```

This will also select entries that may have three or more `@`.  I'm also not sure how much luck you're going to have in splitting them up; I suppose you will use the `.com`.